# Landscape Cross Section of Real Locations

Tags: height-map, bump

I'm trying to use Blender create landscape cross sections like this one [image]

I have to use heightmap data of real locations. 
Creating the distortion just on the top face of the box is working fine, the issue I face are the sides as the texture does not extend along the distortion as you can see in the image below.

Any idea how I can make it look like the example I showed above?

[image]

Comment: It seems that the borders vertices are not affected by the heightmap. Maybe the UVmap of the top face need an adjustment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create vertex group for top part
- Unwrap object before using modifier
- Assign material on sides
- Add Displace Modifier and use this Group

In your case seems like Hieghmap texture does bnot overlap edge. Extend a bit texture size in texture properties or scale UVmap in UV editor.

[image]

[image]

Or you can change Mapping type ...

Clip
[image]

Extend
[image]

Repeat
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! <3
I modified it a bit more and I'm quite happy with where this is going. :)

https://i.imgur.com/7icV8dq.jpg